# Highcharts, how to get data from array on same js page instead of external JSON

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In stockcharts (highcharts) all of their examples on their site extract data from JSON objects through a link. How can I get it from an array on the same page instead?

I have been able to get the chart data from an array on the same js page, but cannot do the same if it's a stockchart.

This is how [highchart stock](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) on the official site gets data:

```
$.each(names, function (i, name) {
    // data from JSON
   $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/' + 
      name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json',    function (data) {
   // .
   // .
   // .
   // etc
```

And this is a fiddle with a stock chart where I am unable to get the data from an array in the same page: https://jsfiddle.net/omaraziz/shjuLtkq/2/

How can I load data from an array in the same javascript page instead of getting it from an external JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been able to get the chart data from an array on the same js
>   page, but cannot do the same if it's a stockchart.

Highcharts and Highstock work the same, so the problem could be with something different.

> How can I load data from an array in the same javascript page instead
>   of getting it from an external JSON?

Just add `series.data` (see: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.data) as an array or object with data. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/shjuLtkq/8/

Code:

```
var usdeur = [
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1), 0.7537],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 2), 0.7537],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 3), 0.7559],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 4), 0.7631],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 5), 0.7644],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 8), 0.769],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 9), 0.7683],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 10), 0.77],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 11), 0.7703],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 12), 0.7757],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 15), 0.7728],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 16), 0.7721],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 17), 0.7748],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 18), 0.774],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 19), 0.7718],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 22), 0.7731],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 23), 0.767],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 24), 0.769],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 25), 0.7706],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 26), 0.7752],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 29), 0.774],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 30), 0.771],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 0, 31), 0.7721],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 1), 0.7681],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 2), 0.7681],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 5), 0.7738],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 6), 0.772],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 7), 0.7701],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 8), 0.7699],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 9), 0.7689],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 12), 0.7719],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 13), 0.768],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 14), 0.7645],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 15), 0.7613],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 16), 0.7624],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 19), 0.7616],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 20), 0.7608],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 21), 0.7608],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 22), 0.7631],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 23), 0.7615],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 26), 0.76],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 27), 0.756],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 1, 28), 0.757],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 1), 0.7562],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 2), 0.7598],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 5), 0.7645],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 6), 0.7635],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 7), 0.7614],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 8), 0.7604],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 9), 0.7603],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 12), 0.7602],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 13), 0.7566],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 14), 0.7587],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 15), 0.7562],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 16), 0.7506],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 19), 0.7518],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 20), 0.7522],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 21), 0.7524],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 22), 0.7491],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 23), 0.7505],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 26), 0.754],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 27), 0.7493],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 28), 0.7493],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 29), 0.7491],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 2, 30), 0.751],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 2), 0.7483],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 3), 0.7487],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 4), 0.7491],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 5), 0.7479],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 6), 0.7479],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 9), 0.7479],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 10), 0.7449],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 11), 0.7454],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 12), 0.7427],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 13), 0.7391],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 16), 0.7381],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 17), 0.7382],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 18), 0.7366],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 19), 0.7353],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 20), 0.7351],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 23), 0.7377],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 24), 0.7364],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 25), 0.7328],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 26), 0.7356],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 27), 0.7331],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 3, 30), 0.7351],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 1), 0.7351],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 2), 0.736],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 3), 0.7347],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 4), 0.7375],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 7), 0.7346],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 8), 0.7377],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 9), 0.7389],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 10), 0.7394],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 11), 0.7416],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 14), 0.7382],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 15), 0.7388],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 16), 0.7368],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 17), 0.74],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 18), 0.7421],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 21), 0.7439],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 22), 0.7434],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 23), 0.7414],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 24), 0.7437],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 25), 0.7441],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 28), 0.7434],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 29), 0.7403],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 30), 0.7453],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 4, 31), 0.7434],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 1), 0.7444],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 4), 0.7418],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 5), 0.7391],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 6), 0.7401],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 7), 0.7425],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 8), 0.7492],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 11), 0.7489],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 12), 0.7494],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 13), 0.7527],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 14), 0.7518],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 15), 0.7512],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 18), 0.7461],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 19), 0.7462],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 20), 0.7449],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 21), 0.7465],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 22), 0.7441],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 25), 0.743],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 26), 0.743],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 27), 0.7443],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 28), 0.7427],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 5, 29), 0.7406],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 2), 0.736],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 3), 0.7353],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 4), 0.7344],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 5), 0.7332],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 6), 0.7356],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 9), 0.7343],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 10), 0.7318],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 11), 0.7272],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 12), 0.7254],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 13), 0.7257],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 16), 0.7257],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 17), 0.7263],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 18), 0.7258],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 19), 0.7237],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 20), 0.7246],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 23), 0.7236],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 24), 0.723],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 25), 0.7277],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 26), 0.7289],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 27), 0.7326],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 30), 0.7322],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 6, 31), 0.7297],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 1), 0.732],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 2), 0.732],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 3), 0.7303],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 6), 0.7238],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 7), 0.7251],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 8), 0.7251],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 9), 0.7285],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 10), 0.7327],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 13), 0.7326],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 14), 0.7359],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 15), 0.7422],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 16), 0.7461],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 17), 0.7434],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 20), 0.7422],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 21), 0.7404],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 22), 0.7412],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 23), 0.7368],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 24), 0.7346],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 27), 0.7323],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 28), 0.732],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 29), 0.7337],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 30), 0.7349],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 7, 31), 0.7298],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 3), 0.7337],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 4), 0.7365],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 5), 0.736],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 6), 0.7317],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 7), 0.7302],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 10), 0.725],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 11), 0.7235],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 12), 0.7203],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 13), 0.7197],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 14), 0.7216],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 17), 0.7207],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 18), 0.7212],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 19), 0.7157],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 20), 0.7129],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 21), 0.7119],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 24), 0.7087],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 25), 0.709],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 26), 0.708],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 27), 0.7053],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 8, 28), 0.7054],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 1), 0.7027],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 2), 0.7061],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 3), 0.7046],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 4), 0.7089],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 5), 0.7075],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 8), 0.7099],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 9), 0.7125],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 10), 0.707],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 11), 0.7044],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 12), 0.7057],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 15), 0.703],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 16), 0.7068],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 17), 0.7043],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 18), 0.6994],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 19), 0.7],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 22), 0.706],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 23), 0.7017],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 24), 0.7028],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 25), 0.699],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 26), 0.6953],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 29), 0.695],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 30), 0.6942],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 9, 31), 0.6923],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 1), 0.6934],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 2), 0.6908],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 5), 0.6903],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 6), 0.6875],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 7), 0.6794],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 8), 0.6819],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 9), 0.6812],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 12), 0.686],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 13), 0.6847],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 14), 0.6804],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 15), 0.6832],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 16), 0.6826],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 19), 0.6825],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 20), 0.6765],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 21), 0.6751],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 22), 0.6745],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 23), 0.6754],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 26), 0.6737],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 27), 0.6724],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 28), 0.6782],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 29), 0.6786],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 10, 30), 0.6776],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 3), 0.6819],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 4), 0.6785],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 5), 0.6794],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 6), 0.6872],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 7), 0.6827],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 10), 0.6795],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 11), 0.6817],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 12), 0.6815],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 13), 0.6812],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 14), 0.6893],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 17), 0.6949],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 18), 0.6938],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 19), 0.6953],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 20), 0.697],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 21), 0.6955],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 24), 0.6946],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 25), 0.6946],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 26), 0.6946],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 27), 0.689],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 28), 0.6807],
    [Date.UTC(2007, 11, 31), 0.6794]
];


Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'xAxis: {min: Date.UTC(2010, 8, 1), max: Date.UTC(2014, 8, 1)}'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }, {
            name: "UK WE",
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```